# Count days inside date period, count the first 7 days separately

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I use SQL Server 2017 and have a table with date periods with a "From date" and a "To date" columns

After I have selected all date periods that overlap with a chosen date period I want to count only the number of days that are inside the chosen date period.
I also want to count the first 7 days separate from the remaining days (only the days that fall inside the chosen period).

example:

Chosen period 2022-01-01 to 2022-01-31

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE [From date] <= '2022-01-01'
AND [To Date] >= '2022-01-31'
```

| ID | From date | To date | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-26 | 2022-02-09 | cut off from and to date |
| 2 | 2022-01-21 | 2022-02-09 | cut off to date |
| 3 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-14 | no cut off |
| 4 | 2021-01-15 | 2022-02-11 | cut off from date |
| 5 | 2020-05-10 | 2020-10-20 | outside chosen period |

Wanted results:

| ID | from date | To date | first 7 days | remaining days | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 | 1 | 30 | cut off from and to date |
| 2 | 2022-01-21 | 2022-01-31 | 7 | 4 | cut off to date |
| 3 | 2022-01-10 | 2022-01-14 | 5 | 0 | no cut off |
| 4 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 | 0 | 31 | cut off from date |

Only the `ID`, `[First 7 days]` and `[Remaining days]` columns in the results table are important and the other columns are only shown in the above example for the purpose of clarity.

I have started writing a series of "case when then" using datediff but it feels overly complicated and I hope there is a better way to do it.

Comment: The data doesn't match between your source data and wanted results. The dates, per ID, differ. For example, ID 1, the from and to dates don't match with the wanted results. Can you adjust or further explain?

Comment: Try starting with a _common table expression_ (CTE) to generate clearly named columns for the various time periods involved: days within the _chosen period_ prior to the `[From Date]`, ... . Then build a query using those values. It may be longer, but far easier to understand. (And another level of CTE may be helpful to sort out the overlaps.) Note that for a simple, i.e. non-recursive, CTE there isn't a performance penalty. The Query Optimizer folds the whole thing up rather than executing it as a series of steps as written. You can edit the code into your question so we can help untangle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  from_date
       ,to_date
       
       ,datediff(day, from_date, to_date)+1-case when datediff(day,fd_plus_7, to_date) <= 0 then 0
             when datediff(day,fd_plus_7, to_date) >= day_max then day_max
             else datediff(day,fd_plus_7, to_date)+1 end as first_7_days
       
       ,case when datediff(day,fd_plus_7, to_date) <= 0 then 0
             when datediff(day,fd_plus_7, to_date) >= day_max then day_max
             else datediff(day,fd_plus_7, to_date)+1 end as remaining_days  

       ,Comment  
from         
        (    
        select *
               ,datediff(day, min(from_date) over(order by from_date) ,max(to_date) over(order by to_date desc)) + 1 as day_max  
        from   (
                select *
                       ,case when [From date] < '2022-01-01' then '2022-01-01' else [From date]  end as from_date
                       ,case when [To date]   > '2022-01-31' then '2022-01-31' else [To date]    end as to_date  
                       ,dateadd(day, 7, [From date]) as fd_plus_7
                from t
                where [From date] <= '2022-01-31'
                  and [To date]   >= '2022-01-01'
              ) t ) t
order by ID
```

| from_date | to_date | first_7_days | remaining_days | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 31 | cut off from and to date |
| 2022-01-21 00:00:00.000 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00.000 | 7 | 4 | cut off to date |
| 2022-01-10 00:00:00.000 | 2022-01-14 00:00:00.000 | 5 | 0 | no cut off |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00.000 | 0 | 31 | cut off from date |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bxfM9tsE?hide=2)

Comment: There may be an assumption floating around as to the length of the _chosen period_. If it isn't a month then your code returns [interesting results](https://dbfiddle.uk/uJ7VNz2R), e.g. `first_7_days` values greater than `7`.

Comment: @HABO See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @HABO for the observation, the chosen period may be any length. I did not test the original code and the new code have been tested by me with slight alteration but I need to study the results from my database in more detail tomorrow.

Comment: @TomMRiddle the new one works.

Comment: @TomMRiddle can you send me the fiddle to check out? I'll update it if needed

Comment: I had made a mistake when changing the column names to be those in the real database, now everything is as your code intended and works perfectly. Thank you for the help @DannySlor